# Why posting values to firebase realtime database using firesharp shows error

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, fire-sharp

I am using firesharp package  for posting values to firebase realtime database 
 from c# code.But SetTaskAsync method throws error , I have followed  same syntax which is referred in youtube tutorial/other blogs.

**Code:**

```
var notification = new AdminNotification { Id = "1234", message = "New Notification", isRead = "false", type ="0" };

IFirebaseConfig config = new FirebaseConfig
            {
                BasePath = "https://*******.firebaseio.com",
                AuthSecret= "**FireBaseApiKey**",

            };
            IFirebaseClient client;
            client = new FireSharp.FirebaseClient(config);

            var response = await client.SetTaskAsync("Notifications/", notification);
```

**Exception is:**

> An error occured while execute request. Path : Notifications/ , Method
>   : PATCH. An error occurred while sending the request. The server name
>   or address could not be resolved

**Stacktrace:**

> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at FireSharp.FirebaseClient.d__b`1.MoveNext()

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Note for AuthSecret : copy Authentication secret from

```
Project settings ->Services account -->Database secrets
```

copy the code beside your project name